# JSP page only showing path to file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea

I am studying Java EE (using Intellij with a WildFly server) and encountered the next problem:

I am working in MVC and the teacher gave us a MVC-template to use. The template itself works just fine but if I include a new JSP page, it won't show up in the browser. The browser will only show the path like this:

[image]

The default 'hello world' is working however (but isn't using a path for a specific reason?: 
[image]

This has made me thinking if this has to do with the MVC-spring approach to programming? But why isn't student.jsp showing? I tried to make a href in the default welcome page for redirecting to it for testing but it still gives me the same 'error'.

What am I doing wrong here? I feel kind of embarrassing asking this since it looks like a very simple problem and specially since I haven't found any related threads about it.

The student.jsp page itself is correct to my knowing:

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="addStudent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run a single .jsp file in any spring project. You can only run projects in the spring framework. So when you include a new JSP page, it won't show up in the browser.

If you want to run your .jsp file then 1) You must run your SpringMVCTemplate project rather than just a file, and 2) The included .jsp file must be in use of the SpringMVCTemplate, not just a simple "hello world" file.

Hope it helps :)